# render multiple elements with same ID in JavaScript HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, browser

I am trying to render Multiple Barcodes with same ID in one HTML Page. Here is my code below.

```
    <html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsbarcode/3.11.3/JsBarcode.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<img id="barcode"
 
  jsbarcode-value="123456"
 />

<img id="barcode"
  
  jsbarcode-value="654321"
 />
<script>
      var element = document.querySelectorAll("#barcode");
      for(var i = 0; i < element.length; i++)     
      JsBarcode(element, {
        format: "code39",
        lineColor: "#0aa",
        width: 4,
        height: 40,
        displayValue: false
});
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But I get an empty page when I open in Chrome.
Please help me in how to render using unique IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So problem is that the first parameter being passed in to the JsBarcode method is an element. You need to pass the string of jquery id. If you look at their documentation it has following:

```
JsBarcode("#barcode", "1234", {
format: "pharmacode",
lineColor: "#0aa",
width: 4,
height: 40,
displayValue: false
});
```

Notice first parameter is "#barcode" not the actual element. In your case it looks like you are passing in element which is not what JsBarcode is expecting. I see your problem and i was able to get it to work with following:

```
<svg name="barcode" 
  jsbarcode-value="123456"
/>

<svg name="barcode"
  jsbarcode-value="654321"
/>

<script>
  var elements = document.getElementsByName("barcode");
  for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)        {
  var id = elements[i].name + "i";
  elements[i].id = id;
  var value = elements[i].getAttribute("jsbarcode-value");
  JsBarcode("#" + id, value, {
    format: "code39",
    lineColor: "#0aa",
    width: 4,
    height: 40,
    displayValue: false
  });
}     
</script>
```

In summary i changed all elements on page to have name="barcode" instead of id. Then set the id using name and the incrementor in for loop which is used to pass a unique id into JsBarcode and get the value from the attribute.

Comment: I am not getting the last barcode generated, anything we need to check in the loop?
suppose I have 3 places where I need to generate the barcode, I am getting the first two places, but the third one isnt displaying.
but when I reload the page it is loading.

Comment: How does barcode get generated? Since this works when you reload the page i am assuming at time loop runs that all barcodes have not been generated?

Comment: I have a HTML code that generates depending on a variable i. Suppose I have i=3, the HTML code runs 3 times and appends to the same file.

the first HTML file is created and the rest 2 times it it appended to the first file to create a single HTML file

Comment: Ok so you need to have the script not run until this process has finished. There are several ways to go about this. Easiest way if possible would be to just make the above a method and call it when the first process finishes.

Comment: Could you update the code on how to do that? I am not that good in JS. Thank you

Comment: Yes if you could provide code where you are updating file i would  be happy to show you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222989/discussion-between-shiva-nara-and-maxqueue).

Comment: Nevermind, I got the onload function working. THank you for the help,

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop there is a mistake

You pass in JsBarcode as first property the element which is an array

Correct like that

```
  var element = document.querySelectorAll("#barcode");
  [].forEach.call(element, function(elem){
    JsBarcode(elem, {
    
    format: "code39",
    lineColor: "#0aa",
    width: 4,
    height: 40,
    displayValue: false
    });
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not have multiple id with same value on html page.
One solution for your case can be to change the id with class and then with selector use the class.

Change id="barcode" to class="barcode", then

```
document.querySelectorAll(".barcode");
```